Proving $\sigma(n) > n + \sqrt{n}$
Question statement, From David Burton's Elementary Number Theory:

For any composite $n$, prove that $\sigma(n)>n+\sqrt{n}$

This question has been resolved here, but I wish to know if the following proof is also valid:
let $n=p_{1}^{\alpha_{1}}p_{2}^{\alpha_{2}}...p_{r}^{\alpha_{r}}$ then we know $\sigma(n)=(1+p_{1}+...+p_{1}^{\lceil{\frac{\alpha_{1}}{2}\rceil}}+...+p_{1}^{\alpha_{1}})...(1+p_{r}+...+p_{r}^{\lceil{\frac{\alpha_{r}}{2}\rceil}}+...+p_{r}^{\alpha_{r}})$
Or, $\sigma(n) = (p_{1}^{\alpha_{1}}...p_{r}^{\alpha_{r}}) + (p_{1}^{\lceil{\frac{\alpha_{1}}{2}\rceil}}...p_{r}^{\lceil{\frac{\alpha_{r}}{2}\rceil}})+X$, Where
$X$ is the sum of all the remaining divisors of $n$.
so, Clearly: $\sigma(n) > (p_{1}^{\alpha_{1}}...p_{r}^{\alpha_{r}}) + (p_{1}^{\lceil{\frac{\alpha_{1}}{2}\rceil}}...p_{r}^{\lceil{\frac{\alpha_{r}}{2}\rceil}}) \geq n+\sqrt{n}$
$\blacksquare$
My problem with this is:

It does not feel like a very rigorous proof (perhaps due to all the dots),


This can be done for any radical of $n$, not just $\sqrt{n}$, so perhaps I am missing some reason as to why the author decided to go with $\sqrt{n}$

I am new to proof writing, would be obliged if someone helps me out. Thanks!
EDIT: $\sigma(n)$ is the sum of all positive divisors of $n$.

Your proof assumes $\lceil\frac{\alpha}{2}\rceil<\alpha$ for each exponent $\alpha$, or equivalently each prime $p$ appears in $n$'s prime factorization with multiplicity not equal to $1$.
